# Implicit constexpr Behavior for const int in C++

Tags: c++, lambda, integer, constexpr

Why are `const int` variables treated as `constexpr` in C++, but this treatment doesn't extend to `const float` or other types? This behavior is observed in the context of lambda captures, where lambdas implicitly capture `const int` variables due to them being considered `constexpr` implicitly, a property not shared with `const float` or other types. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const int variable = 423; // This compiles.
    // const float variable = 423.0f; // This would not compile.

    auto lambda = [] {
        std::cout << variable << '\n';
    };

    lambda();

    return 0;
}
```

Here's a live demo: https://onecompiler.com/cpp/423vje8cj

Comment: Due to a grandfather clause from before `constexpr` existed.

Comment: Related (similar, but for a specific case of `const static` class members) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454019/why-arent-static-const-floats-allowed

Comment: very related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50959021/why-compile-time-floating-point-calculations-might-not-have-the-same-results-as

Comment: It is behavior from before the idea of `constexpr` emerged. The exception for use of `const` integral type variables in constant expressions does not exist in C. In C if you e.g. want a fixed-size array you can only have the array size depend on preprocessor macro values. But in C++ there are templates and e.g. a class template needs to be able to hold an array of a size dependent on a template argument, not only a preprocessor macro. So C++ added an exception for `const` integral type variables that are initialized by a constant expression long before C++11 introduced `constexpr`.